# Find & Replace in notepad++ with regex

Tags: notepad++, regex

I need to convert some old VB.net code to c#, and to speed things up I was planning to use regex.

For instance, in this piece of code:

```
if (Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME").StartsWith("user"))
        userS = true;

if (Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL") != null && Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL").StartsWith("/contai"))
        UseContai = true;
```

I want to replace `Request.ServerVariables("...")` with `Request.ServerVariables["..."]`
I tried using `Request.ServerVariables("(.*)")` to match it, but it's not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parens are a special character in REGEX, as they create a "matching group".  So if you'd need to escape them with a backslash (`\`).  You'd also want to escape the period/fullstop since that also has a special meaning in regex:

```
Request\.ServerVariables\("(.*)"\)
```

However, this is a pretty liberal match - to make sure you only get through the end perem of the `Request.ServerVariables("...")` you may instead prefer:

```
Request\.ServerVariables\("([A-z_]+)"\)
```

That would give you a match between the quotes of only `A-z` and an `_`.

A great resource for you to learn more about Regex is [Regexr](http://www.regexr.com/).  It has a live text editor where you can try out different patterns and see how it matches in your example.  It also has a "Samples" window that gives you hints about what pieces do.

If you want an easier find/replace (and this is not an elegant regex), you could do more matching groups:

```
Find: (Request\.ServerVariables)\(("[A-z_]*")\)
Replace: $1[$2]
```

[See it here](http://regexr.com?387ti)

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that it matches the full line. Is there anyway to make the "matching ending" after the last )
http://regexr.com/?387tf

Comment: I was just updating to show why that was :)  Try that out.

Comment: Sure thing, I just added a potentially time saving fix for you with the replacement - hope that helps!